# Netsuite Returning multiple result for same item - Case When expression

Tags: reporting, netsuite, case-when

I am trying to get a duedate from below function but i am getting multiple result because we have multiple purchase order for 1 item.

case when {locationquantityonorder} > 0 then {transaction.duedate} else null end

I wont be able to use summary type= min or max for this report.

I need either minimum or maximum due date.

Comment: What kind of search is this? Item search? Transaction search?

Comment: What is the actual goal of this search? What business visibility are you trying to add with this search?

Comment: We need to send 846(Inventory Advice) to our customer and they require that we send then product next availability date if its out of stock. With this formula i am getting multiple date and the items are getting listed multiple times.

Comment: Curious why you are unable to use a min or max summary? It seems like you should be able to group by Item, then summarize your formula column by min or max, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the multiple results is because you are returning a search that uses a Location dependent field (i.e. "locationquantityonorder").

Basically, if you display the location with the search result, you will see why the results was returned multiple times - one line for each Location.